# AWSのインバウンドルールの登録の仕方

Tags: aws

AWSのインバウンドルールの登録の仕方がわかりません。現在、ポケットWifiを使っています。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

とこの画面でSSH・TCP・２２カスタム　をそれぞれ選択して、カスタムの横にWifiのアドレスを入れる欄があるのですがここになんて書けばいいのかわかりません。ポケットWifiは例えば123.456.xx.xx とxx.xxの部分で変更されていることはわかるのですが、正規表現みたいにどう書けばいいのかわかりません。

どのように書けば良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

サブネットマスクを IPアドレスの末尾に書く必要があるので `/32` をつけてください。

例）`123.45.67.89/32`

Comment: ありがとうございます。/32はどういう意味ですか？

Comment: /32はサブネットマスク 255.255.255.255 のことで、IPアドレスの全てがホスト部という意味になります。CIDRと言います。AWSではIPアドレスはCIDRで表現する仕様になっています。